# How to begin writing a smart pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I've just received a task in my university, which is to write a smart pointer. I received a skeleton, and I need to implement the needed methods. If I'm right, a smart pointer is a type of pointer which counts the reference numbers to a given object (?) and, if that counter reaches zero, it deletes the given object.

This is the skeleton:

```
template<class T>
class my_pointer {
public:       
    my_pointer();
};

class refcounted {
    /* the reference counted types should have the public interface that is defined here */
public:     
    int incRefCnt();
    int decRefCnt();
};

int main() {
    my_pointer<refcounted> obj1 = new refcounted();
    my_pointer<refcounted> obj2 = obj1;

    return 0;
}
```

Firstly, what should this line do? refcounted is not a child of my_pointer, so how can I possibly instantiate a new refcounted object and reference it with a my_pointer object (pointer?)?

```
my_pointer<refcounted> obj1 = new refcounted();
```

Why isn't there a counter in the my_pointer class, and why is the counter in the refcounted class? How should I start with this? I'm not really good in c++. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "If I'm right, a smart pointer is a type of pointer which counts the reference numbers to a given object" - that's one kind of smart pointer, but not the only kind. For example, `std::unique_ptr` doesn't do that.

Comment: What does this question have to do with c?

Comment: It appears you're supposed to implement an *intrusive* ref-counted smart pointer, where the reference count is stored within the pointed-to object. That's what the two ref count functions do.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, so I need to look into the intrusive ones. And can you tell me something about the line that I pointed out? I just can't seem to realize how that would work.

Comment: It would be better to use a type such as `size_t` for the reference count.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)#Rule_of_5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Firstly, what should this line do?

```
my_pointer<refcounted> obj1 = new refcounted();
```

That line should initialize a `my_pointer<refcounted>` smart pointer from the `refcounted` raw pointer passed to it.

> how can I possibly instantiate a new refcounted object and reference it with a my_pointer object (pointer?)?

You can do it using a [converting constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor). `my_pointer` doesn't have a constructor accepting a `T*`, so it seems to have been left for you to define.

> Why isn't there a counter in the my_pointer class, and why is the counter in the refcounted class?

You're apparently tasked with creating an intrusive pointer that expects the stored object to do the reference counting.

> How should I start with this?

I would take a glance at the description and interface of [boost::intrusive_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html). You probably don't need quite as complete interface for your assignment, though.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding my comment into an answer:

First question: what the line is supposed to do is create a new object of type `refcounted` on the heap, and then use an implicit converting constructor to create a smart pointer that points to this object, incrementing its internal reference count.

Second question: It appears you're supposed to implement an intrusive ref-counted smart pointer, where the reference count is stored within the pointed-to object. That's what the two ref count functions do. Intrusive reference counting has the advantage of being more space-efficient (since you do not need to allocate the reference count separately), and that you can take a raw pointer and simply turn it into a smart pointer, without caring about other smart pointers that already exist. It has the disadvantage of being unable to point to arbitrary types, and not supporting weak pointers.

Third question: You start by thinking about what it means to create, copy, and destroy a smart pointer.